# Set scan time duration

Tags: android, ios, socketscan

Is there a way to set the duration of the scan?  I would like to set how long the laser tries to scan a barcode, is that possible?

I have not found any documentation in the socket mobile SDK that points to this feature or property being available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the scan duration using the following command barcodes

### These instructions are for the 7Ci, 7Di and 8Ci only!

1. Scan the "Scan Duration" barcode
2. Scan *three* numeric barcodes (X, Y, Z) to set the duration to XY.Z seconds. Valid duration values are between 00.5 and 25.5 seconds.

#### Scan Duration barcode

[image: Scan Duration command barcode for the Socket Mobile CHS 7Ci and 8Ci]

#### Numeric barcodes

[image: Numeric command barcodes for the Socket Mobile CHS 7Ci and 8Ci]

Comment: Is it possible to set this programmatically?

Comment: @Mark sorry, that is not supported

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Hi @Enrico, Is there any Socket mobile official document regarding this? If yes, can you please share that?

Comment: @RintoRapheal I don't think so. Why? Are you looking for instructions to set the scan duration on a different model?

Comment: Thanks Enrico, I've figured it out.
Used the Data confirmation methods and am able to control the device feedback.
Also, I've deleted the other question posted, hope you do not mind.